# Managing Java based Desktop Applicationc(Database Management)

Tags: java, desktop-application

I am developing a Java based  desktop application for a school.
As I am beginner, I am facing some issues.

1. Where to store the data of students or teachers (In files or database )
2. If in files, how I will ensure the security ?
3. If in Database, Can I embed db in application  or I need to install db on server.
4. If db is installed on server, how I will manage the application if I will give that to other school users. (Means distributing the application to different users)
5. Do I need to create separate database for different users on servers or Can I make separate schema on same db.

Comment: 1. In database; 2. You could encrypt, but see 1; 3. Yes, or kind of. You can get 100% pure Java based database implementations (H2) which allow single user access (no server required) if you need. The database will need to be stored on the drive of the user; 4. See 3; 5. Not sure what the point would be

Comment: All these questions depend on the requirements for the app.

Comment: You need to ask yourself some simple questions. Is this set up for a single user or do you want multiple users to access the data? If you want multiple users to access the data, then you need to consider a server based implementation, which would mean you'd also want to stop direct access to the database by clients and have them run through some kind of service layer (think web API) - this would further increase the security of the system. You could do this on a site by site bases, so each site would host their own server, on as a central services - but this would change your database design

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

1.Where to store the data of students or teachers (In files or database ) 
If you would like to go with open source databases, go with MYSQL instead of storing in files. Basic user authentication is enough to give you security to get started with your application. So no need of 2nd.

3. You can install and run on a remote system or your local machine depending on your application requirements and budgets.
4. On top your database, to communicate with it, develop a Spring web application (Spring data jpa) with REST web services so that any user can communicate with your application.
   In your data base, you can manage users as well with basic authentication like username, password.
5. No you need not create separate schemas or dbs for each user. Instead you can create a single table that has information regarding Users for your application. For example, create a table "User_Management" which has columns like emailId, phone, name etc.

To get started, you can refer below:
http://javabeat.net/spring-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need Mysql server installed for the following:

1->Store it in Database(mysql database)

2->database security (refer mysql secuity)

3->all you need is mysql connector for java put in the application folder of app you are creating

4->You can provide database inside of folder of application no

5->You can add user in same database.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use Database (the best for this is Derby DB default for Java)
2. You can Embed Derby DB in application and also use this as server client.
3. Derby DB is light weight 2MB.
4. Alternatively you can use MySQL
5. If db is installed on server, You would create server on other school's PC or 
   you have to purchase the online server.
6. The Best as I described is Derby but if you want to use other you can use Xampp , Wampp server for local server client applications.